# WinRT MVVM-Light ComboBox in ListView with different ItemsSources

Tags: c#, listview, combobox, mvvm-light, winrt-xaml

I'm working on a WinRT application where i have a Listview with a ComboBox.
The Listview has a particular ObservableCollection as Itemssource, The ComboBox Should have another ObservableCollection as ItemsSource because i should be able to dynamicaly change the contents of the ComboBox.

I'm using the MVVM-Light framework, The ObservableCollections are filled in the ViewModel and displayed through databinding.

I'll give you an example Xaml code:

```
<Page x:Class="MvvmLight2.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
  mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
  d:DesignHeight="768"
  d:DesignWidth="1366"
  DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Page.Resources>

</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOne}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringOne}"></TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionTwo}" Width="500">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringTwo}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
               </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And Corresponding ViewModel:

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDataService _dataService;
    public MainViewModel(IDataService dataService)
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        CollectionOne = new ObservableCollection<ClassOne>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var temp = new ClassOne()
            {
                StringOne = "String " + i.ToString()
            };
            CollectionOne.Add(temp);
        }

        CollectionTwo = new ObservableCollection<ClassTwo>();
        CollectionTwo.Add(new ClassTwo("ADV"));
        CollectionTwo.Add(new ClassTwo("Wettelijk"));

    }

    private ObservableCollection<ClassOne> _collectionOne;
    public ObservableCollection<ClassOne> CollectionOne
    {
        get { return _collectionOne; }
        set
        {
            if (_collectionOne == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _collectionOne = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CollectionOne);
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ClassTwo> _collectionTwo;
    public ObservableCollection<ClassTwo> CollectionTwo
    {
        get { return _collectionTwo; }
        set
        {
            if (_collectionTwo == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _collectionTwo = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => CollectionTwo);
        }
    }

}
```

In ClassOne and ClassTwo are for the example just one property in each class with a string.

Both collections have to remain seperate because they can be different in length when randomly filled.

**EDIT**
@Josh I followed your instructions but it still doesn't seem to work, Here are my adjustments:

```
<Page x:Class="MvvmLight2.MainPage"
  x:Name="MyControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    d:DesignHeight="768"
    d:DesignWidth="1366"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

<Page.Resources>

</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOne}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringOne}"></TextBlock>
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=CollectionTwo}" Width="500">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringTwo}"></TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the ViewModel Locator to set your datacontext you can reuse this to find the property CollectionTwo.

Your binding would look like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Main.CollectionTwo, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution!

Answer (score 2):

You need to move up one level in the datacontext to search the view  model instead of the item that is bound at the list view level using RelativeSource:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}, Path=CollectionTwo}" />
```

and for WinRT situations, use a control name:

```
ElementName=MyControl
```

instead of searching by AncestorType and give the page a name of 'MyControl'.  It would then look like

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=DataContext.CollectionTwo}" />
```

and your Page would look like

```
<Page x:Name="MyControl"
```

Comment: ha, i was typing out the same thing as your answer appeared, +1 for finishing first

Comment: The problem with this answer is that AncestorType is not available in WinRT. Do you maybe have a workaround? But thanks anyway.

Comment: @DrZoidberg Updated for WinRT scenarios.

Comment: @Josh I've updated my question with your input, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It doesn't work because Page doesn't have a property called CollectionTwo. The path would need to be DataContext.CollectionTwo.

Answer (score 0):

The ComboBox binding is relative to the Binding of the ListItem. So it searches for CollectionTwo as a property of ClassOne. Either look at the RelativeSource to bind to or move the CollectionTwo to class ClassOne. That way, you can easily build up different lists for each ListViewItem.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. But i'm afraid i don't understand what your are trying to explain. I'm a student programmer so i don't understand everything.

Comment: The scope of CollectionTwo is the same as CollectionOne. But your binding assumes the scope being an item of CollectionOne. That means, XAML tries to find CollectionTwo as a property of ClassOne.

Comment: If i understand your answer correctly, i don't think it works in my particular project. Can you maybe clarify it with a little example? Thanks